# jquery moving up/down in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move the elements in the div up/down. Once its moved the item.position has to be swapped with the previous one. Below is the code. Can someone please suggest how to pass the newly assigned position and associated data seq into an array so they can passed to controller and inserted to database

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${entry.value }" >

<ul>
<li> <div class="rows">
          <a id='${item.position}' data-seq='${attr.id}'  class="noDownloadFormat" href="/files/${item.value}" target="_blank"><c:out value="${item.title}" /></a>
         <div style="float:right;margin-top:-15px;">
             <input type="button" class="btn"  value="UP" />

          </div>
      </div>
</li>
<ul>
    </c:forEach>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   $(".btn1").click(function(){
var $current = $(this).closest('li')
var currentval =$(this).closest('li').children().find("a").prop("id");
var prevVal=$current.prev('li').children().find("a").prop("id");

    var $previous = $current.prev('li');
      if($previous.length !== 0){
        $current.insertBefore($previous);
    $(this).closest('li').children().find("a").prop("id",prevVal);
    $current.prev('li').children().find("a").prop("id")==currentval ;
     }
      return false;
    });



    });
```

thanks

I modified the jquery and now I am able move up and down but not able to swap the position

Comment: I think it is better to swap the element `attributes` rather than replacing elements...

Answer (score 0):

I done just up button...
[Tweak it online](http://runnable.com/VSJ7CD9V2OQxpFQY/move-element-up-for-jquery-and-javascript).

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="rows">
            <a id='position1' data-seq='id1'  class="noDownloadFormat" href="#" target="_blank">title1</a>
            <div style="float:right;margin-top:-15px;">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="UP 1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rows">
            <a id='position2' data-seq='id2'  class="noDownloadFormat" href="#" target="_blank">title2</a>
            <div style="float:right;margin-top:-15px;">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="UP 2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="rows">
            <a id='position3' data-seq='id3'  class="noDownloadFormat" href="#" target="_blank">title3</a>
            <div style="float:right;margin-top:-15px;">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="UP 3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var handler = function (e) {
        $li = $(e.target).parent().parent().parent();
        // Avoid delete element if it's at top of list.
        if ($li.prev().size() !== 0) {
            // Move element.
            $li.prev().before($li.remove());
            // Bind click handler to new button.
            $('.btn', $($li)).click(handler);
        }
    };
    $('.btn').on('click', handler);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```